# indentation error in file comparison function

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare line in two file and do something with it . but i'm getting error on indentation and i'm not sure why there is error . 
i will appreciate for any pointer .

[root@localhost ~]# python commit.py

File "commit.py", line 85

```
done = True
^
```

IndentationError: unexpected indent

Code that has error:

```
 75 def compareline():
 76  done = False
 77  for filename in newfilenamelist:
 78   if done:
 79    break
 80   with open(filename) as line:
 81    for list in opendifffilelist:
 82     if not list:
 83      print "List is empty"
 84      done = True
 85     for line in filename:
 86      if list == line :
 87       opendifffilelist.remove(list)
 88       outfile.append(outfile)
 89       break
```

Comment: make sure you do not mix tabs and spaces

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to be running development code as root? Its generally a very bad idea to use root as a developer account.

Comment: Anyway, I wouldn't recommend to develop with the root user. I just say that, maybe you are just doing something quick, we don't know..

Comment: @BurhanKhalid we noted that at the same time :p

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the using root is not recommended .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a first glance your indentation seems correct. This kind of error is often due to mixing tabs and spaces in the source code.

From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces):

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is
>   already indented with tabs.
>
> Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.
>
> Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be
>   converted to using spaces exclusively.
>
> When invoking the Python 2 command line interpreter with the -t
>   option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and
>   spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are
>   highly recommended!

The section just above it is about indentation in general.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer this was the issue indeed , my .vimrc file was culprit here not showing me mixing tabs and space in my code .

Answer (score 0):

Try this formatting. Your error was likely due to mixing tabs and spaces.

```
def compareline():
    done = False
    for filename in newfilenamelist:
        if done:
            break
        with open(filename) as line:
            for list in opendifffilelist:
                if not list:
                    print "List is empty"
                    done = True
            for line in filename:
                if list == line :
                    opendifffilelist.remove(list)
                    outfile.append(outfile)
                    break
```